# Nested lists for matrix transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to Python.
I am trying to transform the columns of the matrix to a single list.

Here is my input

```
   X= [[2,4,3],
      [7,8,2],
      [1,2,0]]
T=[[row[i] for row in X] for i in range(len(X)-1)]
T
```

The output I get is

```
[[2, 7, 1], [4, 8, 2]]
```

However the output I would like to get is something like  this

```
[[2, 7, 1], [4, 8, 2],[3,2,0]]
```

I am a bit struggling with the concept of nested list, and not really sure how can I modify my code in such way so that it works correctly for any number of columns and rows of the matrix.

And note that, I am not allowed to use any external libraries such as NumPy and etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: `[[row[i] for row in X] for i in range(len(X))]` gives the result.

Comment: …and of course the pythonic way: `list(zip(*X))`

Comment: Remove the -1 from the range, range is already run 1 less then the total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `-1` from the `range` argument:

```
T=[[row[i] for row in X] for i in range(len(X))]
```

Remember, range is exclusive of the upper bound.

For a non-square matrix, you can use:

```
T=[[row[i] for row in X] for i in range(len(X[0]))]
```

This takes the new row count from the old column count.

Comment: problem is if I have something like this: X= [[1, 0],
                      [2, 3],
                      [4, 2]] it says that index is out of range. That's why I used Len(X)-1

Comment: @Python_learner See my updated answer.  The bottom version works on non-square matrices.  For the above example, it produces `[[1, 2, 4], [0, 3, 2]]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
X= [[2,4,3],
      [7,8,2],
      [1,2,0]]
T=[[row[i] for row in X] for i in range(len(X[0]))]
```

python `range` is exclusive for it's end argument,so using `range(len(X))` would result in the numbers 0,1,...,len(X)-1

Comment: problem is if I have something like this: X= [[1, 0], [2, 3], [4, 2]] it says that index is out of range

Comment: @Python_learner yes I overlooked this problem, `len(X)` refers to the number of rows, you should use `len(X[0])` for the length of a column, assuming all columns have the same length

Comment: Thank you man! Just out of curiosity, what if columns not necessarily have same length? Then what the code would look like? Because I Think that my data not always have columns with same length...

Comment: @Python_learner well, you couldn't transform it if the columns wouldn't have the same length (mathematically speaking), you could use the minimum length of a column but it would result in losing data. You can get the min with this snippet: `min_col_len = min([len(a) for a in X])`

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a great guy!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)

```
x = [[2, 4, 3],
     [7, 8, 2],
     [1, 2, 0]]

print(list(zip(*x))) # [(2, 7, 1), (4, 8, 2), (3, 2, 0)]
```